# React/CSS: Using CSS stylesheets in a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I have normal css file I would like to use in my React app which is not using webpack. When I try to import the css file, I get the below error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,400i,700,700i");
```

Based on some posts that I have seen online, it looks like you have to webpack and customize it to load the css stylesheet. But is there a way to use my existing stylesheet without webpack ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following line in between the `<head>` of your `index.html` instead...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,400i,700,700i">
```